# not able to access 2 or more files from ajax in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

this is my PHP code

```
for($x=0; $x<count($_FILES['image1']['name']); $x++ ) {

        // echo "Hello";
        $file_name = $_FILES['image1']['name'][$x];

        $file_size = $_FILES['image1']['size'][$x];
        $file_tmp  = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'][$x];
        $lclLocation1 = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/images/".$_FILES["image1"]["name"][0];
        $lclLocation2 = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/images/".$_FILES["image1"]["name"][1];


        $t = explode(".", $file_name);
        $t1 = end($t);
        $file_ext = strtolower(end($t));

        $ext_boleh = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "bmp");

        if(in_array($file_ext, $ext_boleh)) {
            $sumber = $file_tmp;
            $tujuan = "../images/" . $file_name;
            // echo "Image got";
            move_uploaded_file($sumber, $tujuan);

        }
        else  {
            echo "Only Images can be store!";
        }
    } // end for
```

and this is my ajax query

```
  // this contains two images
var lclImage1 = document.getElementById("txtImage1");

    lclImage2 = lclImage1.files[0];

    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("image1", lclImage2);
```

After this, we are sending with ajax to PHP.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "user.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false

});
```

The above PHP Code working fine for directly calling the action with file name I am getting multiple values but if I use ajax then it is not working

below is HTML code

```
<form name="imgupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
     <td rowspan="1">
        <input type="file" id="image1" name="image1[]" multiple>
    </td>
     <input type='submit' name='submit'><br/>
</form>
```

Comment: where is ajax call ???

Comment: just a second i will share

Comment: you declared formData using var keyword ? it should be like => var formData = new FormData();

Comment: No, as follows                                                                                                               formData = new FormData();

Comment: please declare the variable before using it

Comment: Not getting after declare also

Comment: share the html in question

Comment: `document.getElementById("txtImage1")` doesn't exist in your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need form submit event for ajax to work as follows,

```
<form id="imgupload" name="imgupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <td rowspan="1">
        <input type="file" id="txtImage1" name="images1[]" multiple>
    </td>
    <input type='submit' name='submit'><br/>
</form>
<script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>

    $('#imgupload').on('submit', function () {

        var formData = new FormData();            
        var count = document.getElementById('txtImage1').files.length;
        for (var x = 0; x < count; x++) {
            formData.append("image1[]", document.getElementById('txtImage1').files[x]);
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "user.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false

        });
        return false;
    });


</script>
```

user.php

```
for($x=0; $x<count($_FILES['image1']['name']); $x++ ) {

    // echo "Hello";
    $file_name = $_FILES['image1']['name'][$x];

    $file_size = $_FILES['image1']['size'][$x];
    $file_tmp  = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'][$x];
    $lclLocation1 = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/images/".$_FILES["image1"]["name"][0];
    $lclLocation2 = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/images/".$_FILES["image1"]["name"][1];


    if(($_FILES["image1"]["type"][$x] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["image1"]["type"][$x] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["image1"]["type"][$x] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["image1"]["type"][$x] == "image/pjpeg")){
        $sumber = $file_tmp;
        $tujuan = "../images/" . $file_name;
        // echo "Image got";
        move_uploaded_file($sumber, $tujuan);

    }
    else  {
        echo "Only Images can be stored!";
    }
} // end for
```

Also I edited the image extension condition. Because a file name may have period in its name, exploding the name with period would result in an error.

Comment: That is not an issue.

Comment: files can only be accessed with file input, and  it is "upload" not "txtImage1", where is the element with id "txtImage1" element ?

Comment: now you changed the it to "image1"  and you have "txtImage1" in javascript, what you doing ?

Comment: Typing mistake bro.

Comment: I have 2 programs written for debugging I posted here with old program.